# How to use property inside map in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object where I want to reach properties inside. When I type list.activityType i get the error Property 'activityType' does not exist on type 'string'. How can i solve this?

```
  const renderSurveyItem = (
    items: SurveyActivityViewModel[]
  ): JSX.Element => {

    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(items).map((list) => (
          <div className="kpi" key={list}>
            <div className="item text-x"></div>
            <div className="item">
              <div className="kpi-name">{list.activityType}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: A key is a string. `Object.keys` returns an array of keys.

Comment: Please post the json, what is the value for `items` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `map` on an array of the **keys** of the properties in `items`. Looking at your code, you just want to call `map` on `items` itself, using the item it provides and perhaps also its index (key):

```
const renderSurveyItem = (
  items: SurveyActivityViewModel[]
): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="kpi" key={index}>
          <div className="item text-x"></div>
          <div className="item">
            <div className="kpi-name">{item.activityType}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note I changed `list` to `item`, if the items really are lists (their type suggests they aren't) and `list` makes more sense, there's no reason you can't change it back.

---

Note that using an array index as a `key` is usually not recommended, details [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). It's fine for arrays whose entries are never moved around or removed, but otherwise you want to use some unique identifier that's intrinsic to the object itself (`item`) rather than where it is in the array.